# ASP.NET not calling code behind even in debug

Tags: c#, asp.net

as it says, when I run my application in debug the code-behind isn't being called.

I had this problem to start with and managed to get around it by abandoning the page I was working on and starting a completely new one.

However it seems this one has now broken also!

Basically it just opens showing the unaltered HTML without running any of the C# code and without hitting any breakpoints.

It builds ok but I haven't tried deploying it yet as I don't have a server available at the moment.

This is my code behind from index.aspx.cs:

```
namespace PAPS
{
    public partial class index : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { 
            string username = User.Identity.Name;
            // check security
            Security security = new Security(username);
            divUsername.InnerText = username;
            security = null;
        }
    }
}
```

The page declaration from index.aspx is as follows:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="false" EnableSessionState="True" EnableViewState="false" CodeBehind="index.aspx.cs" Inherits="PAPS.index" %>
```

Anyone have any useful suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have

```
AutoEventWireup = false
```

Unless you're handling the events yourself, try setting that to true.

Comment: I will be using jQuery to handle the events - I hate all those postbacks! Is this really likely to be causing the problem? I've done this before with no issues...

Comment: @bukko you can use jQuery for client side events, but if you want Page_Init and Page_Load to run before the page is served, set it to true.